# How to store a TYPO3 site configuration inside a site package?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

With TYPO3 `9.x` [Site Configurations](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.2/Feature-84581-SiteHandling.html) were introduced.

In my TYPO3 composer installation the site configurations are stored in `/sites/sitepackagename/config.yaml`

I would like to know whether it's possible or not to include the site configuration inside a [site package](https://typo3.org/article/typo3-site-package-tutorial).

I'm aware of the possibility to use imports inside the site configuration (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164496/how-to-extend-typo3-site-configuration-without-editing-config-sites-mysite-confi)) and link to a `.yaml`file inside my site package. But I'm looking for a solution without manually touching `/sites/sitepackagename/config.yaml`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is **not possible**. The two possible locations (depending on whether you are in composer mode or not) are `<project-root>/config/sites/` and `typo3conf/sites/`.
This is also described in the [docs](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Basics.html#site-configuration-storage).